# Mysql - get highest and lowest 5 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT dmn_name AS domain, COUNT(*) AS newsletters, SUM(mwl_sended) AS emailsSent, SUM(IFNULL(nwl_ca, 0)/mwl_sended) * 1000 AS ecpm FROM domain
                JOIN newsletter USING(dmn_id)
                WHERE dmn_actif = 1
                AND nwl_sendedOn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                AND nwl_sendingEndedOn is NOT NULL
                GROUP BY dmn_name
                ORDER BY ecpm DESC
                LIMIT 5
```

It returns 5 results having highest ecpm. How would I modify it to return 5 highest AND 5 lowest? I want to avoid executing the query two times.

Thanks

Comment: there's no practical way to do a "dual zone" result like that. you can fake a single query by using a union, and each sub-query does the max/min stuff, but now you've got 3 queries running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT dmn_name AS domain, COUNT(*) AS newsletters, SUM(mwl_sended) AS emailsSent, SUM(IFNULL(nwl_ca, 0)/mwl_sended) * 1000 AS ecpm FROM domain
                JOIN newsletter USING(dmn_id)
                WHERE dmn_actif = 1
                AND nwl_sendedOn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                AND nwl_sendingEndedOn is NOT NULL
                GROUP BY dmn_name
                ORDER BY ecpm DESC
                LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT dmn_name AS domain, COUNT(*) AS newsletters, SUM(mwl_sended) AS emailsSent, SUM(IFNULL(nwl_ca, 0)/mwl_sended) * 1000 AS ecpm FROM domain
                JOIN newsletter USING(dmn_id)
                WHERE dmn_actif = 1
                AND nwl_sendedOn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                AND nwl_sendingEndedOn is NOT NULL
                GROUP BY dmn_name
                ORDER BY ecpm ASC
                LIMIT 5
ORDER BY ecpm DESC
```

Comment: I would probably use `UNION ALL`

Comment: That's a good point. We don't want to assume the results from each SELECT won't intersect.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about unions and subqueries. If there is no other option, I guess UNION ALL is the best decicion. Although a small remark - first and second SELECTs should be wrapped into brackets. Thank you